# Conversion of character into datetime in R

Tags: r, function, datetime, type-conversion, character

How to convert a column of character "2020-08-12T04:31:41Z" into datetime. I have tried as.POSIXct() function, but, when I give value to format it returns NA.

Comment: `lubridate::ymd_hms(c("2020-08-12T04:31:41Z"))`

Comment: @Stephan Thanks. It worked. By the way do you know why it was showing NA first

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the time using `utctime` from the `anytime` package or `as_datetime` from `lubridate` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(date = "2020-08-12T04:31:41Z")

library(anytime)
utctime(df$date, tz="UTC")
#> [1] "2020-08-12 04:31:41 UTC"
library(lubridate)
as_datetime(df$date)
#> [1] "2020-08-12 04:31:41 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use strptime which creates a datetime object from the given string

```
strptime("2020-08-12T04:31:41Z", tz = "UTC", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")
```